# Don't know how to attach a CRC code to my programme

Tags: c++, file, crc

I'm writing a programme where I have to read a file and then divide it to smaller ones. After that I have to merge them into one file, which has to be like this one before dividing. I gotta check both files with CRC. I already have a CRC code, but don't know how to attach it to my programme. I don't know which arguments should I send to *data and size. Thank you so much for help.

```
#define CRC16 0x8005

uint16_t gen_crc16(const uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
    uint16_t out = 0;
    int bits_read = 0, bit_flag;

    if(data == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(size > 0)
    {
        bit_flag = out >> 15;

        out <<= 1; 
        out |= (*data >> bits_read) & 1; 

        bits_read++;
        if(bits_read > 7)
        {
            bits_read = 0;
            data++;
            size--;
        }

        if(bit_flag)
            out ^= CRC16;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        bit_flag = out >> 15;
        out <<= 1;
        if(bit_flag)
            out ^= CRC16;
    }

    uint16_t crc = 0;
    i = 0x8000;
    int j = 0x0001;
    for (; i != 0; i >>=1, j <<= 1) {
        if (i & out) crc |= j;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

And here is my programme's code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void podzial_pliku(string rozmiar, string nazwa_pliku);
void scalanie_plikow(string nazwa_pliku);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(string(argv[1])=="p")
        podzial_pliku(argv[2],argv[3]);
    if (string(argv[1])=="s")
        scalanie_plikow(argv[2]);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}


void podzial_pliku(string rozmiar, string nazwa_pliku)
{
    char bufor[1024];
    fstream plik_do_podzialu;
    plik_do_podzialu.open(nazwa_pliku.c_str(),ios::in);

    if (!plik_do_podzialu.is_open())
    cerr << "Nieudane 1 otwarcie pliku " << nazwa_pliku << " do odczytu." <<         endl;

    plik_do_podzialu.seekg(0,ios::end);
    int rozmiar_pliku = plik_do_podzialu.tellg();
    plik_do_podzialu.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    int ile; 
    int rozm = atoi (rozmiar.c_str()); 
    ile = rozmiar_pliku / rozm;


    int rozmiar_ostatniego_pliku;
    if (rozmiar_pliku % rozm != 0)
    {
        rozmiar_ostatniego_pliku = rozmiar_pliku % rozm;
        ile += 1; 
    }


string numer[4];
string nazwa_nowego_pliku[200];
for (int i=0;i<ile;i++)
   {
    numer[2]=i%10+'0'; 
    if (i>=10)         
        numer[1]=(i/10)%10+'0';
    else numer[1]='0';
    if (i<100)        
        numer[0]='0';
    else numer[0]=(i/100)%10+'0';

    string nazwa = "";
    int p = 0;
        while (nazwa_pliku[p] != '.') 
        {
        nazwa += nazwa_pliku[p];
        p++;
        }
    nazwa_nowego_pliku[i] = nazwa + numer[0] + numer[1] + numer[2] + ".dat";
   }

int i=0;
while (i<ile)
    {
    plik_do_podzialu.read(bufor,rozm);
    fstream podzielone_pliki;
    podzielone_pliki.open(nazwa_nowego_pliku[i].c_str(),ios::out);
    if (!podzielone_pliki.is_open()) 
    cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku " << nazwa_nowego_pliku[i] << " do odczytu." << endl;
    podzielone_pliki << rozmiar_pliku << " " << ile << " " << nazwa_nowego_pliku[i+1] << "\r\n" << endl; 
    podzielone_pliki.write(bufor, rozm); 
     podzielone_pliki.close();
    i++;
    }

fstream podzielone_pliki;
podzielone_pliki.open(nazwa_nowego_pliku[ile-1].c_str(),ios::out);
plik_do_podzialu.read(bufor,rozmiar_ostatniego_pliku);
if (!podzielone_pliki.is_open())
    cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku " << podzielone_pliki << " do odczytu." << endl;
podzielone_pliki << rozmiar_pliku << " " << ile << "\r\n" << endl;
podzielone_pliki.write(bufor, rozmiar_ostatniego_pliku);

plik_do_podzialu.close();
}

void scalanie_plikow(string nazwa_pliku)
{
int rozmiar, ile;
string nastepny_program;

fstream pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia;
pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia.open(nazwa_pliku.c_str(), ios::in); 
if (!pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia.is_open())
    cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku " << nazwa_pliku << " do odczytu." << endl;

pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia >> rozmiar >> ile >> nastepny_program; 
fstream scalony_plik;
scalony_plik.open("scalony_plik.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
    if(!scalony_plik.is_open()) 
        cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku scalony_plik.dat do odczytu" << endl;
string linia;
getline(pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia,linia);
while(!pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia.eof())
    {
        getline(pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia,linia);
        scalony_plik << linia;
    }

pierwszy_plik_do_scalenia.close();
for (int i=1;i<(ile-1);i++)
{
    int rozmiar, ile2;
    fstream kolejny_plik_do_scalenia;
    kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.open(nastepny_program.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (!kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.is_open())
        cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku " << nastepny_program << " do odczytu." << endl;

    kolejny_plik_do_scalenia >> rozmiar >> ile2 >> nastepny_program;

    string linia;
    while (!kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.eof())
    {
        getline(kolejny_plik_do_scalenia,linia);
        scalony_plik << linia;
    }
    kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.close();
}
fstream kolejny_plik_do_scalenia;
kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.open(nastepny_program.c_str(), ios::in);
if (!kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.is_open())
    cerr << "Nieudane otwarcie pliku " << nastepny_program << " do odczytu." << endl;

kolejny_plik_do_scalenia >> rozmiar >> ile;

while (!kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.eof())
{
    getline(kolejny_plik_do_scalenia,linia);
    scalony_plik << linia;
}
kolejny_plik_do_scalenia.close();

scalony_plik.close();
```

}

Comment: It looks like the function's expecting a pointer to your data and its size. Can you show the code where you're supposed to do the calculation?

Comment: Of course, I've edited my post and added there that code

Comment: data is a pointer to whatever you want the crc16 of. size is the # of bytes that this data occupies.

Comment: ***I've edited my post and added there that code*** I am not sure that helped. You added a lot of code. Not sure what part is relevant. Also I don't know this language so its hard to read.

Comment: I'm really new to programming. Could you please tell me straight what arguments should I send there?

Comment: I don't know where you even want to use this code so its difficult to answer.

Comment: I need to use it twice, after opening a file plik_do_podzialu and after opening scalony_plik

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must pass to your CRC implementation a pointer to the data buffer. If you have enough memory and the data is small enough, to load the buffer with the whole file contents, and then pass to the CRC function the pointer of the buffer and its very length.
It's a lot that I don't use C but...

```
uint8_t *data = NULL;
uint8_t *dataOffset = NULL;
uint16_t fileLength = 0;
uint16_t fileCRC = 0;
size_t readBytes = 0;
FILE *fp = NULL;

fp = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
fileLength = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
data = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * fileLength);
dataOffset = data;
while((readBytes = fread(dataOffset, sizeof(uint8_t), 1024, fp)) > 0)
{
    dataOffset += readBytes;
} 
fclose(fp);
fileCRC = gen_crc16(data, fileLength);

// Now you can check if the new CRC is the same as the old one.
```

I've not compiled it, so there can be erros. Also, dataOffset pointer can go out of bounds if something go wrong, so you must first validate the correct pointer offset.

Comment: The instruction was not to load whole file and assume that the file is very huge

Comment: Then you probably want to turn the crc16 function into a class feeding it a part of your file at a time. Although with that said you said you were new to programming and c++. I would say the whole assignment is unreasonable for someone just learning the language.

Comment: @drescherjm Class apart, I cannot undertstand your answer. If you assuming I'm new to c++, I'm not. Why the assignment is unreasonable? For bleis if you don't compute CRC on the whole file, you're computing CRC only of the single chunks. CRC(A XOR B) = (CRC A) XOR (CRC B). Crc is a checksum for messages, if you split the whole file in chunks, and you don't fill them with spaces, the XOR of the progression of various CRC is not the CRC itself. If it's ok for you, you can surely calculate the CRC of the single chunks.

Comment: I was not talking about you, @bleis said that they were new to programming and c++. This is clearly not a project you give someone who is just beginning to learn programming.

Comment: I agree. It not only needs to know at least well C/C++, but also need to know mathematics behind CRC. It's not easy for a beginner to complete this task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the crc function to take the crc as an input.

```
#define CRC16 0x8005

uint16_t gen_crc16(uint16_t crc, const uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
    int bit_flag, i;

    if(data == NULL)
        return crc;

    while(size-- > 0)
    {
        crc ^= ((uint16_t)(*data)) << 8;    // xor in next byte
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){             // cycle crc for 8 bits
            bit_flag = crc >> 15;
            crc << = 1;
            if(bit_flag)
                crc ^= CRC16;
        }
    }
    return crc;
}
```

The main code would look like:

```
uint16_t crc = 0;
// ...
// loop
//  read a chunk of the file
    crc = crc16(crc, bufor, size);
// ...
```